# Graphics card started having issues and makes my computers unable to boot except in PCIe 2.0 x1 slot

Tags: boot, graphics-card, motherboard, hardware-failure, pci-express

First post here, and glad to be able to start participating now after much time reading the topics to be found around... :)!.

I have a graphics card (regular 1080) that started having issues a few months ago.

The card will work perfectly and as intended, as well as draw all of the 208W it is limited to, using its single 8-pin connector, in the open-ended single lane PCIe 2.0 slots I have on my old ASRock mobo perfectly, though my attempt to use it on the brand new mobo I have's PCIe 3.0 closed 1x slots (which I have cut and filed the end off of) wasn't successful.

The issue it has is that when I attempt to boot it using either of the main slots intended for GPUs, be they 16X, 8X or 4X electrical, the computer will refuse to boot. The motherboard will power on all the fans and auxilliaries, but the CPU seems to refuse to cooperate being the culprit here as far as I can tell as the fans will spin once (literally) on one of the boards - and continue spinning but not proceed to POST on the other board - and then nothing more happens from there.

Obviously, I am not getting a POST screen at all here, no matter which of the video output I use (even if on a separate GPU - which also doesn't help the computer boot when used.), and have no way to tell what is going on here exactly.

With the card stuck at 1x AND on PCIe 2.0, it's unusable for most gaming applications due to the bandwidth limit, basically being relegated to a mining and output card now, it's kind of sad to see it behaving this way because unfortunately I need it for its DVI output, and am thus for now forced to use my older motherboard which is inferior and less useful in many ways than the new one. Not to mention using it this way will disable the onboard LAN port, forcing me to use its wifi which is far from ideal as a gamer and streamer.

On top of spending easily a dozen hours reading about PCIe and its technical specs, and of course a fair bit of googling around though sadly (or not, haha.) nobody else seems to have ever had this issue, I've tried many things so far to try and diagnose and fix this problem by myself, including disabling the M.2 ports, nearly all IO and compatibility related BIOS options or anything that looked like it could remotely have an impact, using electrical tape to mask the pins not used for 1x cards (which would've at least given me something to go with), inspecting the card visually to see if everything looked alright, and probably many more that don't come to mind right now as it's been a while since I gave up on fixing it by now haha.

So far, I'm still clueless to what the cause is and what I could do to help... I don't even understand how it's even working in 1x@2.0 mode, since if I understood correctly the PRSNT#1 pin is supposed to be connected to the furthest PRSNT#2 pin on the board and it's only connected to the pin 17 one - although it's a 16x board. Doesn't seem like it's communicating that fact to the motherboard heh.

Hate to give up and go around and ask for help, but... I'm at that point now. Would love to either use the card as a main card and sell the other one potentially or at least keep it as a secondary but get my LAN back some day!

Thank you everyone for your attention and any help or ideas you might be able to bring... :)

Comment: You research that this *shouldn't* happen was, as far as I'm aware, correct. PCIe should negotiate down quite happily. Some graphics cards might have a VBIOS update from their manufacturer which can fix things.  Also worth checking the BIOS with your new motherboard, it might be that they have a bugged firmware that broke PCIe in very subtle ways.

Comment: Also, don't rule out any on-board graphics receiving video output OVER the PCIe card. Sometimes you have to hook up an old monitor to the VGA port to enter the BIOS, set the output to PCIe and have it sorted. In some rare cases, PCIe is always used if detected but BIOS is always displayed over VGA still.

Comment: This story is so strange. Hopefully filing off the end of the PCIe slot wasn't your first idea when trying this? If you can't get the computer to post even with a different card I don't see why you're so hung up about that card as clearly something else is wrong with that computer. Also there are passive adapters for HDMI to DVI and DP to DVI.

Comment: Indeed, the story is quite strange, indeed. I have no onboard graphics as it's a Ryzen PC, using my other card for video was no use, I HAVE tried all of the VBIOSes available (all 6 of them or so) on TechPowerup, have tried it on 2 different motherboards (X470 Master SLI/AC from ASRock and X570 Gigabyte AORUS Elite non-wifi model) and 3 processors, a 2700X, a 3800X and a 5800X. Sadly none of these steps helped, either. (As I said, I mentioned a few things I've done but there's many I didn't mention and most likely forgot haha.) Filing off the PCI slot was definitely not my first idea but nope.